# How to block remote login for certain ip/userdomain combination

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

So i have a server "Y", and a user pc "X" allowed to have remote access on this server.

I have a admin domain user (Admin) that has remote access on the "Y" server.

The user X has access to login through they PC with they domain user but also with the "Admin"

How can i block the computer/IP of user "X" to login remotely to the server with the user "Admin" but to be allow to login with they user?

Change the password of "admin" user is not possibly.

Thnx for the help

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/deny-user-permissions-to-logon-to-rd-session-host

You can achieve a Deny Remote Desktop Connection with the Group Policy Management either on the domain level or on the local level.

Here is a way how to achieve it on the local level:

1. Windows + R and then type gpedit.msc
2. Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment.
3. Open "Deny logon through Remote Desktop Services"
4. Add the user that you would like to deny
   Click ok.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. In this way i will Deny all the IP using this X user to login remotely on this server. I need only certain IP to be blocked to login with the X user, not all.

Comment: Hi, I understand. I see no problem in this. You just need to create a Firewall rule with a Scope to the specific IP addresses on the port 3389 and an Auhorized users (Local Principals or Remote Users).

Comment: Hi, In the firewall rule i cannot select an Authorized users (Local Principals or Remote Users) when  the option allow/block the connection is selected. i can select only the Ip.